# Confirmar InputQuery com apenas um Enter

Tags: delphi

Estou utilizando um *InputQuery* para possibilitar ao usuário ter acesso rápido a outras partes do sistema. O problema é que o processo é para dar agilidade e pressionar duas vezes a tecla *Enter* vai na contra-mão do objetivo proposto.
Esclarecendo, ao pressionar uma vez a tecla *Enter*, o foco vai para o botão OK e ao pressionar mais uma vez a tecla *Enter* o botão **OK** é pressionado.
O que quero é que ao pressionar a primeira vez o *Enter*, já seja simulado o pressionamento do **OK**.
Sei que é possível criar um novo *InputQuery* para atender o que preciso.
Mas desejo saber se é possível e se sim, como fazer no *InputQuery* padrão fornecido pelo **Delphi**.

```
  if (InputQuery('Acessibilidade', 'Digite a tela', sTela)) and (Trim(sTela) <> '') then
  begin
    try
      sTela := Trim(StringReplace(sTela,'''','',[rfReplaceAll]));
      Query1.Close;
      Query1.SQL.Clear;
      Query1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM TELAS ');
      Query1.SQL.Add('WHERE TELA = '+Aspas(sTela));
      Query1.Open;
      if Query1.IsEmpty then
        Application.MessageBox('Tela inválida.','Atenção',MB_OK+MB_ICONINFORMATION)
      else
        Abre(Query1.FieldByName('tela').AsString);
    finally
      Query1.Close;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Testei aqui no Delphi 10, e no inputQuery, o Enter já executa o botão OK.
Poderia postar o código que você está utilizando ?

Comment: @VictorTadashi Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Seu código funcionou perfeitamente aqui. o InputQuery vai abrir uma tela, solicitando o nome do programa, essa tela do InputQuery, tem como default o botão OK, ou seja, se você pressionar Enter, vai disparar a ação desse botão. A não ser que o seu problema é na tela que eu abri pelo InputQuery.

Comment: Você matou a charada! Lembrei agora que tenho um componente a nível de aplicação que simula o *TAB* ao pressionar o *Enter*. Não tinha pensado nessa possibilidade.

Comment: Só um adicional: quando pressiona a tecla Enter e o botão OK automaticamente é pressionado é ocasionado pelo `ModalResult`, no caso da ImputQuery o botão OK esta configurado por padrão como MrOk.